# Appending a line just after the matched pattern in sed not working

Tags: regex, linux, sed, pam

My `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` has the below `auth` parameters set:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

I want to insert `pam_tally2.so` just after `pam_env.so`. So I want it to be:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

The script that I'm using is :

```
#! /bin/bash

grep "pam_tally2" /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
   sed -i '/^[]*account[]*required[]*pam_unix.so/aauth\trequired\tpam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
else
   sed -i 's/.*pam_tally2.*/auth\trequired\tpam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900/1' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
fi
```

But it gives this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 116: unterminated address regex
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `change []* to [ ]*`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks much. Small typos in script can be so problematic sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `a` command in gnu-sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/pam_env\.so$/a\
auth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900
' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
```

---

**EDIT:** Looking at your posted answer it seems this `awk` command will be more suitable for you than `grep` and 2 `sed` commands in `if/else` condition:

```
val='auth\trequired\tpam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900'
awk -v val="$val" '/^auth[[:blank:]]+required[[:blank:]]+pam_env\.so/ {
   print $0 RS val; next} /pam_tally2\.so/{next} 1' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac

auth        required      pam_env.so
uth         required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below sed command.

```
sed 's/^auth[[:blank:]]\+required[[:blank:]]\+pam_env\.so/&\nauth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900' file
```

Your regex fails because you're repeating an empty character class `[]`, zero or more times, which won't make any sense. So you need to change `[]*` to `[ ]*` or `<space>*` to repeat an empty space character zero or ore times.

Answer (score 0):

My Script actually should have been:

```
#! /bin/bash

grep "pam_tally2" /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
   sed -i '/^[ ]*auth[ ]*required[ ]*pam_env.so/aauth\trequired\tpam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
else
   sed -i 's/.*pam_tally2.*/auth\trequired\tpam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900/1' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
fi
```

Works fine!